# add context menues to nautilus for comparing directories with meld

Tags: nautilus, context-menu

I'm pretty used to winmerg when working on windows, and it has a really nice feature.

It adds an option to the explorer context menu that says 'compare to...' the first time you use it, and then it says 'compare' and 'change first folder'.

When you click on compare, it launches winmerge with both folder compared.

Is there some way to achieve the same in nautilus for meld?

Right now I'm running it form the command-line passing both directories as parameters

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You simply need to install the `nautilus-compare` package to have a similar context menu.

Comment: This is not available for 22.10.  Any idea how one can integrate Meld with Nautilus on 22.10?

Comment: @JuanAntonio I've moved from Gnome to KDE Plasma long time ago, but it's very easy to do this manually for file managers like Dolphin, Nautilus and Thunar. All you need is the command `meld %U`. It depends how you put this command in use for each specific file manager though. I find Dolphin much more flexible and customizable than Nautilus.