# Integrating Meld with nautilus on 22.10

Tags: nautilus, context-menu, meld

Some time ago, it was possible to get `meld` integrated with `nautilus` in that one could select two files in `nautilus`, right-click to get the context menu which included the command *Compare with meld*.  This could be easily done by installing `nautilus-compare` as [clearly stated in this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/263745/add-context-menues-to-nautilus-for-comparing-directories-with-meld).  However, for quite some time now (maybe since I upgraded to 20.4, or it might have been before), I have not been able to find an alternative.

[This post also talks about a potential solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/688742/add-meld-in-the-contextual-menu); however, it seems something is still missing.

Are there any (easy to install) alternatives to add this functionality in Ubuntu 22.10?